# Can Wix3 check if a service exists?

Tags: service, installation, wix, wix3

Does Wix 3 have a built in way to just check whether a service exists? The closest guess I can come up with is using ServiceConfig and trying to detect a failure.

Comment: You can check registry entries.

Comment: I could do that too. I was just wondering if there was built-in support to check services.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know about that.  Hopefully there is.  But checking registry entries is easier than the ServiceConfig thing.  :)

Comment: You're right. I think that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 1):

The AppSecInc. Community MSI Extensions has a Service_Exists custom action.
http://msiext.codeplex.com

Online Documentation:
http://code.dblock.org/Source/msiext/1.2/Docs/_custom_actions_2_system_tools_2_service_impl_8h.html#a6fdcddc7b04a310a368c08726d3be6b3

```
<Binary Id="SystemTools" SourceFile="$(var.BinDir)\SystemTools.dll" />

<CustomAction Id="SetServiceName" Property="SERVICE_NAME" Value="Service1" />
<CustomAction Id="ServiceExists" BinaryKey="SystemTools" DllEntry="Service_Exists" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action="SetServiceName" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
     <Custom Action="ServiceExists" After="SetServiceName">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

SERVICE_EXISTS is set to "1" if service exists, "0" otherwise.